# JS/ CSS files not found due to path differences java, spring mvc, velocity

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc, velocity

I have this directory structure:

```
webapp
 - resources
   - custom.js
   - base.css
 - WEB-INF
 - views
   - layout.vm
   - top.vm
   - footer.vm
   - index.vm
   - FolderA
     - restricted.vm
```

My layout.vm is:

```
#parse('top.vm')
$screen_content
#parse('footer.vm')
```

My top.vm consists include these JS and CSS files:

```
<link href="resources/base.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="resources/custom.js"></script>
```

Now when my I access http://www.example.com:8080/index page, I see the JS and CSS files getting found.
But when I visit http://www.example.com:8080/FolderA/restricted, JS and CSS files are not found. It works when in top I change it

But then the index page is broken.

I am using spring controllers to return the appropriate views.
For e.g. The following returns the index page:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Model model) {       
    return "index";
}
```

and this returns the restricted view:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/FolderA")
public class SomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String secured(Model model) {

        return "FolderA/restricted";
    }
```

Any suggestions as to how I can fix this issue?

On a side note, I was facing this issue when using regular jsp files as well, but I managed to fix it using `<c:url ..>`. I dont know how this can solved in velocity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thats because the resources you have declared are relative to the url used for accessing the view.
You have to change all the static resource urls to absolute
You can do this using  [tag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_url_tag.htm)

change from this

```
<script src="resources/custom.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/custom.js"/>"></script>
```

this should generate something like this in the HTML

```
<script src="<c:url value="http://www.example.com:8080/FolderA/resources/custom.js"/>">
</script>
```

Note
But for this to work you should add
`%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>` to your jsp 
and include [jst tag library](http://jstl.java.net/) into the webapp

**Edit------**

For the paths referred inside in JS and CSS files , there is a work around.Use [base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) to 
define the absolute path tags in the HTML need to use

```
<base href="http://www.example.com:8080/FolderA/">
```

Comment: I had written that I used <c:url..> in jsp but for some reason it didnt show up. I am more interested in how it can be done in velocity because I know how I can do in jsp file.

Comment: yes. that solves the issue. Thanks a lot!
Just curious, are you aware of any other way to do this on the server side? Something equivalent on <c:url..> ?

Comment: There is an alternative , but thats crude , you will have to embedd all your JS and CSS inline in the HTML . Glad i was able to help you .Please upvote it as well cheers