# amcharts not getting displayed when run on tomcat server(localhost)

Tags: javascript, tomcat, localhost, amcharts

I'm trying out examples of Amchart from their website. When I open the html file on the browser(without running it on a server) the chart is getting displayed properly. But then when I run the same code on localhost(tomcat server) the chart is not getting displayed. I'm not sure if somethings wrong. Can you please let me know if you have encountered any similar issues or am I missing something.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Arun S.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.

Made a mistake in referencing the js and css file.
The webapp folder structure was different for jetty and tomcat (which i used for testing and production)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106978/js-css-files-not-found-due-to-path-differences-java-spring-mvc-velocity) should help you understand